# UIView/ViewController name [picture]

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

What is the name of the UIView/UIViewController in the left upper corner of the attached picture?

And more general question: where could an iOS developer find full and illustrated list of all available UIViews and ViewControllers?

Sorry, don't have enough reputation to attach the picture, please follow the link: [image with iphone interface mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjiL9.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't a controller, it's a `UIActionSheet`. Also, the XCode documentation is pretty useful for browsing through iOS classes. To get to it, press the button in the top right-hand corner of XCode, labeled "Organizer".

More on `UIActionSheet`, you declare one by calling:

`initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:`

Make sure to set your controller as the delegate and to implement:

`actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:`

to specify what should happen when a button is clicked.

To show the Action Sheet initially, it has a bunch of `showFrom...` methods to specify where it will appear on the screen (for iPad, at least).

Comment: Thanks! Just implemented — that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Though browsing for UI elements in XCode built-in documentation is not exactly what I wanted, as a) there are sometimes no illustration pictures b) you should manually browse dozens of pages though I wanted to have some sort of "cheat sheet".